For any sets $A$ and $B$, if $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) = \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$ then either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.
I need help verifying whether the proof by contradiction method I have employed in proving this particular theorem is correct or not.

For any sets $A$ and $B$, if $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) = \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$ then either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.
Proof. Suppose $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) = \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$. Suppose $A \nsubseteq B$ and $B \nsubseteq A$. Then one can let $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ be elements for which $y_{1} \in A~\backslash~B$ and $y_{2} \in B~\backslash~A$ respectively. It follows that there is an element $x_{0} \in \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$ for which $y_{1} \in x_{0}$ and $y_{2} \in x_{0}$, but $x_{0} \notin \mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B)$; so $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) \ne \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$. But this contradicts with the fact $\mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B) = \mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$. Therefore $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.


I would be more explicit and write $x_0={y_1,y_2}$.

The equality implies that $A\cup B\subset A$ or $A\cup B\subset B.$ In the first case $B\subset A,$ while in the second one $A\subset B.$

Yes, that works, but Will's recommendation would make it clearer.
There is a proof without using contradiction.
Suppose $\mathscr P(A \cup B) = \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$.
We know $A \cup B \in \mathscr P(A \cup B)$. So by our assumption $A \cup B \in \mathscr P(A)$ or $A \cup B \in \mathscr P(B)$. So $A \cup B \subseteq A$ or $A \cup B \subseteq B$. But that means $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.
You can also weaken the condition to  $\mathscr P(A \cup B) \subseteq \mathscr P(A) \cup \mathscr P(B)$.
